# Storing and accessing Key, IV remotely Protected Configuration Provider in ASP.NET Framework 4.8

Tags: asp.net, encryption, key, aes, password-protection

We have been encrypting DB credentials with [Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dtkwfdky(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). This is a .NET Framework 4.8 web application. The path is given to "keyFilePath" and the Key and IV values are now saved locally. Our cyber team, however, suggested that we relocate this to a secure area.  Subsequently, we have stored the Ky, IV in a remote machine that has an API that returns these values in a JSON format.
How do we approach that?

**Note:-** There are articles on using Azure Key vault. It is not in our roadmap to upgrade our  legacy application anytime soon.

```
<configProtectedData>
    <providers>
        <add name="MyCustomProvider" useMachineContainer="false" keyContainerName="MyKeyStore" description="CustomProvider to encrypt and decrypt" type="PCP.MyAlgo,MyAlgo,Version=0.0.0.0, CultureInfo=neutral,PublicKeyToken=88031de5f175f38,processorArchitecture=MSIL" keyFilePath="D:\CONFIG\Keys.txt" />
    </providers>
</configProtectedData>

<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="MyCustomProvider">     <EncryptedData>QeYOn9UrgkVGBcrkMNyU9Ed0hChyUTQFUjPIoYeVMdjBTv9V8GFy7V2n0mEQb7dxf5QfRyzOqrJN9QBiP6S2IseQvQv7PRty8bPQnU2EVD4QquUVcDytNv4bRiWuHU3ygRFJtHzFygQRVQ9dQBmSXoQbpQHvUn3qVor/yn7QSvzByt6+9j3yik9zUBrIcWRSBzPrGjDJHQt</EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Edit#1:**
If there is a sample using the Hashicorp vault, it will help. Their documentation has an example using.NET Core but not.NET Framework

Comment: your question is not clear to me. as you mentioned, you are already stored everything on remote machine and accessing via API. so what is the problem now ?

Comment: The path is given to "keyFilePath" and the Key and IV values are now saved locally. keyFilePath="D:\CONFIG\Keys.txt"  <---This is local path which is working fine. How to modify if these are moved to a secure location and accessas JSON format key,iv pair.

Comment: you would have to provide a way again via API to update them. but it is as good as keeping them locally. if you really want to secure them then using some kind of secret management system like azure key vault or hashicorp vault is the way forward. just moving to another server would also result in same security issue.